# Publishing a .net 8 web.api to Azure is causing an error : System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: when attempting to open a sql connection

Tags: c#, azure

I have published a c# web.api in .net 8 to an azure web.api resource.

When I go to open a connection to SQL I'm met with the following error:

```
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information. (Parameter 'name')
en-us is an invalid culture identifier.
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.InternalOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have set the following in the project properties:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This works locally.

When I publish to Azure and look at the files on Azure I notice in the runtimeconfig.json:

{
"runtimeOptions": {
"tfm": "net8.0",
"frameworks": [
{
"name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
"version": "8.0.0"
},
{
"name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
"version": "8.0.0"
}
],
"configProperties": {
"System.GC.Server": true,
"System.Globalization.Invariant": true,
"System.Globalization.PredefinedCulturesOnly": true,
"System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false,
"System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
}
}
}

I didn't have this issue when running on a .net 6 instance. Can somebody please help and explain how I should go about fixing my issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Rob

Comment: I just edited my answer with new information regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, .NET 8 now defaults to `globalization invariant mode` if you don't specify otherwise as [detailed here.](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1913)

In order to enable access to cultures, you're going to need to update one of these settings:

`runtimeconfig.json`

```
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
         "System.Globalization.Invariant": false
      }
   }
}
```

`Project file`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

[More documentation here regarding Globalization configuration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization)